# Difference between Python self and Java this

Tags: java, python, this, self

I had done a bit of Python long back. I am however moving over to Java now. I wanted to know if there were any differences between the Python "self" method and Java "this".

I know that "self" is not a keyword while "this" is. And that is pretty much what I could figure out. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: What do you mean by "self method"?

Comment: You also don't have to have `self` (or in Java's case, `this`) as the first parameter of a class method in Java.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**About `self` in Python (here is the source: [Python self explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)):**

The reason you need to use *self*. is because Python does not use the @ syntax to refer to instance attributes. Python decided to do methods in a way that makes the instance to which the method belongs be passed automatically, but not received automatically: the first parameter of methods is the instance the method is called on. That makes methods entirely the same as functions, and leaves the actual name to use up to you (although *self* is the convention, and people will generally frown at you when you use something else.) *self* is not special to the code, it's just another object.

Python could have done something else to distinguish normal names from attributes -- special syntax like Ruby has, or requiring declarations like C++ and Java do, or perhaps something yet more different -- but it didn't. Python's all for making things explicit, making it obvious what's what, and although it doesn't do it entirely everywhere, it does do it for instance attributes. That's why assigning to an instance attribute needs to know what instance to assign to, and that's why it needs *self*..

**About `this` in Java being explained by Oracle (here is the source: [Java this explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)):**

Within an instance method or a constructor, *this* is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using *this*. 
The most common reason for using the *this* keyword is because a field is shadowed by a method or constructor parameter.

Answer (score 133):

First of all, let me correct you - `self` is not a method. Moving further:

Technically both `self` and `this` are used for the same thing. They are used to access the variable associated with the current instance. Only difference is, you have to include `self` explicitly as first parameter to an instance method in Python, whereas this is not the case with Java. Moreover, the name `self` can be anything. It's not a keyword, as you already know. you can even change it to `this`, and it will work fine. But people like to use `self`, as it has now become a bit of a convention.

Here's a simple instance method accessing an instance variable in both Python and Java:

Python:

```
class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        # declare and initialize an instance variable
        self.radius = radius

# Create object. Notice how you are passing only a single argument.  
# The object reference is implicitly bound to `self` parameter of `__init__` method
circle1 = Circle(5);
```

Java:

```
class Circle {
    private int radius;

    public Circle(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}

Circle circle1 = new Circle(5);
```

**See also:**

- [Wiki page of `this`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_%28computer_programming%29)

Comment: Thanks, much more helpful than the copy/pasted accepted answer, IMHO

Comment: Thanks - very helpful answer as it compares the two side by side.

Comment: If there is an existing python method that doesn't have self as the 1st parameter because the Author didn't have a need to access the instance's attributes and later decides to add it back, does this introduce any backward-incompatibility? I'm assuming no because every Python method is passed the self instance automatically.

Comment: Concise and on point. Thank you! Better than the chosen answer

Comment: Be aware of the difference in case of in inheritance and overriding as mentioned by @林果皞. 
If you have a parent-child class hierarchy, in Java `this` in parent refers to parent, but in python `self` in parent refers to the child.

Answer (score 16):

Be careful **super can keep its own version of this.i in Java**, but **self.i always refer to the child in Python**.

**Main.java:**

```
class Parent {

    int i;
    Parent() {
        this.i = 5;
    }

    void doStuff() {
        System.out.println(this.i);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    int i;
    Child() {
        this.i = 7;
    }
}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child m = new Child();
        System.out.println(m.i); //print 7
        m.doStuff(); //print 5
    }
}
```

**Main.py:**

```
class Parent(object):
    i = 5;
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 5

    def doStuff(self):
        print(self.i)

class Child(Parent, object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.i = 7

class Main():

    def main(self):
        m = Child()
        print(m.i) #print 7
        m.doStuff() #print 7

m = Main()
m.main()
```

**Output:**

```
$ java Main 
7
5
$ python Main.py 
7
7
```

**[Update]**

The reason is because Java's `int i` declaration in `Child` class makes the `i` become class scope variable, while no such variable shadowing in Python subclassing. If you remove `int i` in `Child` class of Java, it will print 7 and 7 too.

Comment: The practical advice though, is to not use the same variable name in both child and parent, and that is true for both languages.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective, the most obvious difference is that in java class, in the constructor, you need to specify the field

```
this.radius = radius
```

While in the python code, you don't have to do so, it's implicit.

Comment: Don't you have to do that in python too? If you want to refer to `radius` with `self` then you need to give it the attribute