# How to convert date to text in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Guys if you know any other methods please tell about them. 
This function gives the error:

> 'str' object is not callable.

```
from datetime import date

def datetowords(date):

    day_, month_, year_ = int(date[:2]), int(date[3:5]), int(date[6:])
    print(date(day=day_, month=month_, year=year_).strftime('%A %d %B %Y'))


datetowords("02.11.2013")
```

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-python) SO question and the answers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is variable shadowing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734399/what-is-variable-shadowing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your parameter name from `date` to `gottendate` or something else, because it conflicts with `date` from `datetime` module.

So when you call `date(...)` it calls the inner `date` variable, since python looks for the local scope first.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @ori6151, you can simplify and speed up your code using the split() function and list comprehension.

**For example:**

```
from datetime import date

def datetowords(string):
    day_, month_, year_ = [int(i) for i in string.split('.')]
    print(date(day=day_, month=month_, year=year_).strftime('%A %d %B %Y'))

datetowords("02.11.2013")
```