# List of Strings to Strings

Tags: python

How can I turn this

```py
list = [['I','am','a','hero'],['What','time','is','it']]
```

to this

```py
list = [["I am a hero"],["What time is it"]]
```

This doesn't work:

```py
list(chain.from_iterable(list.str.split(',')))
```

And neither does:

```py
[a for a in list]
```

Comment: Your expected result contains bunch of syntax errors. Also I do not recommend you to use `list` or any other name which shadowing built in functions/classes.

Comment: `[I am a hero]` is not valid Python.  Did you mean `['I am a hero']`?

Comment: Yes sorry I edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the list items:

```
list1 = [['I', 'am', 'a', 'hero'], ['What', 'time', 'is', 'it']]
list2 = [[' '.join(item)] for item in list1]
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[['I am a hero'], ['What time is it']]
```

Comment: Oh? Apologies for the poor vocab. Any resources where I can read further? @wjandrea

Comment: @YaakovBressler, it's more nitpicking, don't take it seriously. Collision is just not right word.

Comment: Ah. Simple Wikipedia search provides clarity. @OlvinRoght

Comment: @Yaakov No problem! You've got the right idea. I'm not aware of any resources specifically talking about collision (I don't think Python even has collision), but for shadowing, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53734745/4518341) for a quick overview and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) for a more technical definition, plus read about scope: [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/4518341)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it

```
lst = [['I','am','a','hero'],['What','time','is','it']]

new_list = [[' '.join(x)] for x in lst]
print(new_list)
```