# How python does mangle object name and class definitions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand about private variable and about name mangling in python.

When I defined class like this, it throws `AttributeError`

```
>>> class E():
    def __test():
        print("__test()")
>>> c = E()
>>> c.__test()
AttributeError: 'E' object has no attribute '__test'
```

I want to understand the exact reasons, for this error. Can any one explain them clearly?

Comment: This is like 3 or 4 different questions rolled into one...

Comment: have you found very similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821/1358308...  what can we add here that hasn't been said before?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Sorry, for that. As those are inter linked with each other, asked in a single question. Can you please help me to understand them clearly?

Comment: As for the `self` vs. `something`: the name doesn't matter, as long as you understand that the first argument will be the object that invoked the method.

Comment: Name mangling is a rather advanced feature, and rarely used in practice. You should concentrate on more basic things: for example, the first argument of your methods should be `self`...

Comment: To understand *exactly* what is going on, you need to understand the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). Once you understand that, you just need to know that the `function` type implements the descriptor protocol, with `function.__get__` returning a (bound) `method` value that wraps the original function.

Comment: But name mangling and how methods work are two entirely separate questions.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, question was edited to limit it to a specific problem. Can you please tell for whom should I ask to review and remove `hold` flag?

Comment: There must be a duplicate that covers this.

Comment: @Pythoncoder The first edit after question closure automatically puts it into the reopen review queue. But chepner's right, it'll just be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll refer you to [Python's documentation on name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).

> Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores,
>   at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   `_classname__spam`, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped.

So this raises an `AttributeError` because the `__test` methods has been implicitly renamed:

```
class E:
    @staticmethod
    def __test():
        print("foo")

E.__test() # AttributeError
```

But can be made to work by using the mangled name `_E__test`:

```
class E:
    @staticmethod
    def __test():
        print("foo")

E._E__test() # prints 'foo'
```

Notice that I had to add a `staticmethod` decorator due to your method not taking a `self` argument. This is out of scope, but you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self-in-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990099/explaining-the-python-self-variable-to-a-beginner) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694901/difference-between-python-self-and-java-this).

Comment: Thanks for answering. What is the difference between defining class as `E()` and `E`? Please explain this.

Comment: @Pythoncoder None at all